# Compare 2 values in a excel file and get the common values

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to extract a particular data using python. I have 1 month data which consists of how many jobs have failed with a mentioned return code over the 1 month duration.

I have 30 excel files and so far i have loaded the data into my dataframe using the below code :

```
import glob2
import os
import pandas as pd

def concatenate(indir="C:\\Users\\hp",outfile="C:\\Users\\hp\\new1.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    filelist = glob2.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    for f in filelist:   
       print(f)    
       df = pd.read_csv(f)   
       dfList.append(df)
    concatDf = pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)        
    b = concatDf[['JOB NAME' , '  RC  ']]
```

i have extracted the required columns and i have to perform a operation on them such that i know in 1 month data how many jobs have failed with same reasons

input :

```
 STATUS     JOB NAME    RC      DATE    TIME
 R          ABCDEFGH    U0900   18163   19:53
 X          SSTUFGHI    C0001   18164   2:04
 R          LMNOPQRS    SB37    18164   2:41
 R          ABCDEFGH    U0900   18164   3:36
```

O/P required :

```
JOB NAME      RC    
ABCDEFGH    U0900   
ABCDEFGH    U0900
```

i am not understanding how do i compare the 2 values and get the above o/p.Please help me i am very new to python